# When I subclass a class using ByteBuddy in certain situations I get IllegalAccessErrors. Why?

Tags: byte-buddy

(I am a new ByteBuddy user.  I'm using ByteBuddy version 1.10.8 and JDK 11 without the module path or any other part of the module system.)

I have a nested class declared like this:

```
public static class Frob {
  protected Frob() {
    super();
  }
  public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello!";
  }  
}
```

(Its containing class is `foo.bar.TestExplorations`.)

When I create a dynamic subclass of `Frob` named `foo.bar.Crap` like the following, everything works OK as I would expect:

```
final String className = "foo.bar.Crap";
final DynamicType.Unloaded<?> dynamicTypeUnloaded = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Frob.class)
  .name(className)
  .make();
final Class<?> mySubclass = dynamicTypeUnloaded
  .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
  .getLoaded();
assertNotNull(mySubclass);
assertEquals(className, mySubclass.getName());
final Object frobSubclass = mySubclass.newInstance();
assertTrue(frobSubclass instanceof Frob);
```

But if I change `Frob`'s constructor so that it is package private, I get the following error from the final assertion:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class foo.bar.Crap tried to access method 'void foo.bar.TestExplorations$Frob.<init>()' (foo.bar.Crap is in unnamed module of loader net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader @5e3d57c7; foo.bar.TestExplorations$Frob is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

For some reason, `Crap`'s constructor cannot call `super()`, even though `Crap` and `Frob` are in the same package, and `Frob()` is defined as package-private.

I have a sense the JDK module system is to blame here, even though I am deliberately (very, very deliberately) not using it.  I know the module system does not like split packages, which is what it looks like to me is going on here.  Is there a constructor strategy or other mechanism to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, a package is only equal to another package if it has the same name and is loaded by the same class loader (the same as it is with classes). If you are using the `WRAPPER` strategy, you cannot access package-private members of any super class. Byte Buddy does not forbid the generation as it would be legal to do in javac but you would need to use the `INJECTION` strategy to do what you want to make sure that classes are loaded by the same class loader. Mind that it uses internal API, therefore, from Java 9, you'd rather use a `ForLookup` class loading strategy.

Comment: Excellent; thank you; I assume you mean `UsingLookup` (https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.8/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/ClassLoadingStrategy.html)?